# Labels disappear in greater scales in QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis

I'm having an issue with labels which disappear from QGIS while zooming in. I set up the property **Show all labels for this layer(including colliding labels)** to have them all yet it has no effect. This issue is affecting my composer, I can't see any label on it.

Comment: Labels can be displayed based on scale, options for this are in the bottom sub-tab for labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Layer Properties-> Labels-> Rendering are Label options for scale dependent or pixle size-based visibility of the Labels. Maybe check these settings.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's concerning the composer, I assume it's the already mentioned scale depending visibility.

But sometimes it *seems* that the labels disappear. Because of a long rendering time on large projects. In that cases the vectors are rendered quite some time before the labels appear.
Check the status bar if QGIS is busy or not:
[image]